# How to generate a unique name for each uploaded file?

Tags: python, flask

I am building a Flask website, and I want to save a path of a file to my sqlite database

I have a "create" view, where user uploads an image and it gets stored in a folder

```
  @app.route('/create', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
  @login_required
  def create():
    if request.method == "POST":
      file = request.files['file']
      if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
          filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
          file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return render_template('create.html')
```

I want to store a 'path' to each image in my sqlite database. To do this, I think, every filename should be unique. So how should I generate a unique name for each uploaded file?

Comment: What about [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to generate a unique file name would be to just use a numbering system (first file being 1, then increasing by 1). Like so:

```
   counter = 0 #put this at the beginning of your script
```

then when creating file name:

```
   counter += 1
   filename = counter
```

If you do not want your files to be named just numbers you could hash the number to generate a unique code, like so:

```
counter += 1
filename = counter.encode("utf-8")
filename = hashlib.sha224(filename).hexdigest()
```

If doing the latter, you would want to save this code somewhere associated with the user so you can open it again.

Comment: If I use the first method everything works, but it saves a file without an extension. I can add it manually,  like:  `+ ".png"`  . Is it a good practice, or should I better preserve the original extension?`